# How to select a option in combobox with spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, forms

its my first post :)
I want to select an option of the combobox, and depend of this option y want to print one label or other one. For example if I selected option->dni the label would be DNI: or if I selected option->nombre the label would be Nombre:

```
   <div class="campos">
    <div class="campo">
        <form:label path="buscarPor">Buscar Por:</form:label>
        <div>
            <select name="buscarPor" id="buscarPor">
                <option value="dni">DNI</option>
                <option value="nombre">Nombre</option>
                <option value="Departamento">Departamento</option>
                <option value="Área de Conocimiento">Área de Conocimiento</option>
            </select>
        </div>



    <script type="text/javascript">
    function cargarLabel(){
        var seleccionado = $(this).val();
        if(seleccionado == 'dni'){

            $('#seleccion').html('<div class="campo">'+'<form:label path="seleccion">DNI:</form:label>'+
                    '<div>'+'<form:input path="seleccion"/>'+'<form:errors path="seleccion"/>'+'</div>'+'</div>');
        }if(seleccionado == 'nombre'){

            $('#seleccion').html('<div class="campo">'+'<form:label path="seleccion">Nombre:</form:label>'+
                    '<div>'+'<form:input path="seleccion"/>'+'<form:errors path="seleccion"/>'+'</div>'+'</div>');
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $('#buscarPor').change(cargarLabel);
    });

    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="campo">
    <form:label path="seleccion">??</form:label>
        <div>
            <form:input path="seleccion"/>
            <form:errors path="seleccion"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, change the `path` attribute of your `<form:label path="buscarPor">Buscar Por:</form:label>` to something else. Spring tag library generates an `id` attribute of the same value and that will directly conflict with the `id` attribute of your select tag. That is the reason why in your current code, jquery is selecting your `label` tag instead of the `select` tag and binding the `change` event to it.

That said, also take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ganesh/FpeFb/) for the correct way to approach this problem. I think your approach is too verbose and you can do yourself a favor by avoiding all those if/else blocks.

Comment: If this answered your question, can you kindly upvote and accept this answer?

Comment: I can't vote because i don't have reputation, im noob in this page sorry